# Use of .XSD file in C#

Tags: c#, database, xsd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Role of Designer.cs File in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101073/role-of-designer-cs-file-in-c-sharp)

I came across .xsd files in my project. These files are used for creating schema for tables. Can any one help me in understanding the use of xsd in c# and how we can handle databases in detail.

Comment: which database are you using?  Normally you would use an ORM of sorts to interact with the database.

Comment: @HansPassant - this is not the same question as the Designer.cs file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xsd.exe to create strongly typed DataSets from the .xsd files.

[Generating Strongly Typed DataSets (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wha85tzb.aspx)

> Given an XML Schema that complies with the XML Schema definition
>   language (XSD) standard, you can generate a strongly typed DataSet
>   using the XSD.exe tool provided with the Windows Software Development
>   Kit (SDK).