# Why would this code be placed in a *.Designer.cs file?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

In a project I'm maintaining, the original developer put this code at the top of the main form's Designer.cs file:

```
private void MemberListBox_Load()
{
    DataTable dtMembers = null;
    SQLServer sqlDAL = null;

    sqlDAL = new SQLServer(Properties.Settings.Default.BIDataConnection);
    sqlDAL.CommandTimeout = 120;
    DataSet dsMember = sqlDAL.runSQLDataSet("select PoisonToe from PlatypusData..Members where abs(ActiveFlg)=1 Order By PoisonToe", "Members");
    dtMembers = dsMember.Tables[0];

    MemberListBox.DataSource = dtMembers;
    MemberListBox.DisplayMember = "PoisonToe";

    foreach (DataRow unitDPRow in dtMembers.Rows)
    {
        string x = unitDPRow[0].ToString();
        MemberListBox.SetItemChecked(MemberListBox.FindString(x), true);
    }
}
```

Wouldn't MainForm.cs be a more usual location for such code? What is the purpose of having it in MainForm.Designer.cs? Should I move it out to MainForm.cs?

Comment: `original developer put this code` it's a dark path, trying to figure out why developers do the things they do.

Comment: Probably a mistake by original developer, just move it to form behind class.

Comment: Pretty sure that's a mistake.  You shouldn't put user written code in *.Designer.cs

Comment: Move it from .designer, *.designer files are auto generated and could result in loss of data.

He put it there because he didn't know that.

Reference:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101073/role-of-designer-cs-file-in-c-sharp

Comment: It's not a bug it's a feature :)

Comment: Idk, maybe he tought it would be easier for him to navigate inside of the class and see the components, but it is a mistake to manually modify .designer files.

Comment: No one here can tell you what motivated someone we don't know to do something. It's certainly not a good idea to edit the *.Designer.cs file, but when it happens, it could be for any number of reasons, well-intentioned or not.