# Giving file in the project a name A.Designer.cs will make it nested to A.cs

Tags: c#, nested, projects-and-solutions

I just discovered an interesting feature of Visual Studio (using VS2022), **renaming** existing class or **creating new** with same name as another class plus `".Designer"` will make it nested to another class.

To example for a simple console project:

[image]

Nothing in csproj-file indicates it is nested. I would normally expect something like

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Update="Localization\LocalizedStrings.cs">
    <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
    <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
    <DependentUpon>LocalizedStrings.tt</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
  <Compile Update="Views\SoftwareView.axaml.cs">
    <DependentUpon>SoftwareView.axaml</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
   ...
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10103366/1997232) explaining different roles of designer files. It seems they are expected to be autogenerated and treated specially.

Earlier I was using [addon](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.FileNesting).

Question: is it safe to use this "trick" to make something nested? I hope nothing will get overwritten? Are there more tricks related to auto-nesting files by name or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it was

### Bad idea

Certain features are not working inside such `".Designer.cs"` file.

1. Some (all?) warnings are not shown (e.g. C8618) for classes inside this file. The compilier errors are shown and stopping build as normal though.
2. Code Cleanup doesn't perform anything: doesn't format, doesn't remove unused using, etc. But Intellisense support is fully working or at least I didn't noticed any difference.

That's already bad enough.

VS is treating such files differently, assuming they are indeed auto-generated by some tools and leaving only bare minimum of checking. Not *designed* to be edited by human.